# Devise error message customization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am trying to build a rails app with devise, but whenever an error is thrown up by devise it is shown at the top below the header which gets blocked by my other styles and is not seen. How can i show the devise error message inside forms, like this:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name), :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal, left' }) do |f| %>
        {flash message here}
```

which gets shown up inside forms styles.

Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the views using `rails generate devise:views` [as described on their github page](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-views) - this will allow you to move items around within the views.

Comment: I am not talking about the `<%= devise_error_messages! %>`, i am talking about flash messages like: "Signed in successfully."